# Converting acceleration (g) or(m/s^2) to velocity (mm/s)

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator, velocity, vibrations

I have a set of acceleration values taken from accelerometer given in 'g' or 'm/s^2'. I would like to convert it to velocity 'mm/s'. is  there any formula to convert it?

Note: I don't have time or frequency values to convert like this: Velocity = Acceleration * Time.

Comment: How would an acceleration ever be a velocity? You can't "convert" an acceleration to a velocity. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi salvatore, I am taking vibration data from a motor using accelerometer. this gives output in 'g' value i.e, Acceleration values. i want to change it to velocity 'mm/s'..  refer this link  http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1743 . it is possible to change it. but i want to know  whether its  the correct way to do it. since my reading is in 'g' and not 'mV/g'

Comment: As you can see in the thread that you have posted, you really need the frequency. I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish, but I see that you're dealing with vibrations: to convert those datas, you really do need a time, like the frequency. There is no way around it.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) It might help people if you gave more details about your setup - because maybe there is a meaningful way _in your special case_ to convert the two things which are fundamentally different ...

Comment: hello sanya, i have three  axis  vibrational measurements from an accelerometer  having sensitivity of 100mV/g  This gives output in 'g'  (eg : x = -0.234 ; y = -0.42 ; z =2.34 ) . Now i want to change this 'g' (m/s^2) to 'mm/s'.

Comment: if you have the acceleration data to "convert" that to velocity you have to integrate the samples over time: $\frac{dv}{dt}=a$ therefore $v(t)=\int_{t_0}^{t}a(x)dx + v(t_0)$

Comment: Are you just taking the sample once and trying to find it's velocity, or is this sampling with some constant frequency?  If it samples with constant frequency you can use that frequency to determine the time passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your question, as written, doesn't make sense. You cannot convert an acceleration into a velocity unless you know the time over which the acceleration acted (using the equation you quoted yourself, $v=at$).

Since you're dealing with vibration, you have an oscillation; the displacement, velocity and acceleration are all changing with time.

- If we start at the centre of the oscillation, $d=0$, $v=v_{max}$, $a=0$.
- When the oscillator moves to the end-point (just before it starts to come back), $d=d_{max}$, $v=0$ and $a=-a_{max}$.
- As it passes the centre again, moving in the opposite direction, $d=0$, $v=-v_{max}$, $a=0$.
- Finally, at the other end-point, $d=-d_{max}$, $v=0$, $a=a_{max}$.

The acceleration and displacement are proportional (Hookes's Law) but in anti-phase (they point in opposite directions). Velocity is $\pi\over2$ out-of-phase with $a$ and $d$.

Read up on [the simple mass on a spring](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-0/Motion-of-a-Mass-on-a-Spring) to get an idea of how it works.